# Limit of a functional

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

I'd like to find:
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\qquad \mbox{ in }\mathcal D'(\mathbb{R})
$$
And I started with the definition:
$$
\left\langle \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2},\varphi\right\rangle
$$
After doing the integration by parts I had some problems with the support of $\varphi$. I think the result could be $0$, but I don't know how to prove it in a proper way. (during the proof I used the substitution $x=\varepsilon y$ or $y=\varepsilon x$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$T_\varepsilon(\varphi):=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\varphi(x)\mathrm dx.$$
Then, after the substitution $x=\varepsilon t$, we obtain 
$$T_\varepsilon(\varphi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\varphi(t\varepsilon)\mathrm dt.$$
Using dominated convergence, we obtain that for each $\varphi\in\mathcal D(\mathbf R)$, 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}T_\varepsilon(\varphi)=\varphi(0)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt =\pi\varphi(0).$$